# CSS terminology: what are these called?

Tags: css, terminology

Consider:

```
p {
  ...
}

.foo {
  ...
}

#bar {
  ...
}
```

What is the correct name for these statements in CSS? I've seen them called selectors, rules or rulesets, but which is correct?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

A rule would be considered:

`p {…}`

A selector in this case is:

`p`

A rule is made up of selectors and declarations. A declaration is `property:value` so the entire rule would be:

`selector { property:value }`

A rule can have multiple declarations and multiple selectors so we can actually have:

```
selector, selector2
{
  property:value;
  property2:value;
}
```

A rule set would be multiple rules.

Here's a quick [source](http://www.microsoft.com/typography/web/designer/css02.htm) on this or the [CSS 1 Specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS1/#basic-concepts).

Answer (score 5):

CSS is made up of a number of rules in the form

```
selector{declaration}
```

So the .foo and #bar and p are called selectors but the full statement with the curlies are called rules.

Answer (score 1):

They are selectors - [see W3C specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html)

Answer (score 0):

According to the [specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html), they are called Selectors.

Answer (score 0):

In this example:

```
p.class, #id > a {
foo:bar;
}
```

`p, #id > a` is group of selectors. `p.class` and `#id` are selectors. Selectors are built from simple selectors and combinators: `p` is a type selector, `.class` is a class *selector* (not a class). Combinators are '`+`', '`>`', '', etc.

`selectors {...}` is a rule. It's a mistake to call it class.

`foo:bar` is a declaration for `foo` property.

http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/grammar.html

Answer (score 0):

CSS rules: Selector, Declaration Block, Property, Declaration, and Declared value.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

I usually call them rules or classes.