# What is the definition of the noun "style" in CSS?

Tags: css, terminology

What does the noun "style" (plural "styles") mean exactly in the context of CSS?

I've taken a look at a few terminology / glossary pages, but they don't seem to cover this word:

- https://css-tricks.com/css-ruleset-terminology/
- http://nimbupani.com/css-vocabulary.html
- https://www.impressivewebs.com/css-terms-definitions/
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Syntax
- https://www.hongkiat.com/blog/css-back-to-basics-terminology-explained/
- https://www.codecademy.com/articles/glossary-css

---

Here is an example of a terminology definition, which is what I'm looking for:

**Selector**
A selector is the part of the CSS line that selects what element to target with the property/value pair. In the example below “#container #box” is the selector:

```css
/* the selector is everything on the first line */
/* excluding the opening curly brace */
#container #box {
  width: 200px;
}
```

Comment: is this *progamming related*? I don't think such question belong to SO

Comment: @TemaniAfif I think that terminology is a very valid programming topic. Also - I looked around and found many other terminology-related questions (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/terminology) including very similar questions by prominent members: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1120264/css-terminology-what-are-these-called

Comment: I know terminology is a valid topic and it's important to understand the meaning of some words in order to correctly write a CSS code (like knowing the difference between *block formatting context* and *containing block*) but not sure if it's the case here. (PS: you linked to a question asked 10 years ago ..)

Comment: "Style" and "styles" are very common terms and it is very difficult to find a good definition for them. I believe this is reason enough to ask the question.

Answer (score 0):

The closest that I've gotten to an answer is that "Style" refers to a declaration:

```css
.a {
/*┏━━━━━ Style aka Declaration ━━━━━━┓ */
  background-color: mediumspringgreen;
}
```

And thus "Styles" refers to multiple declarations.

I base this on colloquial usage:

> Property: The style that you are applying to a selector, e.g. border.
>   Selector: The way you declare which elements the styles should apply to.

Ref: http://nimbupani.com/css-vocabulary.html

---

> an element that has a class of “navigation” will receive the declared styles.

Ref: https://www.impressivewebs.com/css-terms-definitions/

---

> div[attrib^="1"] { /* styles here */ }

Ref: https://www.hongkiat.com/blog/css-back-to-basics-terminology-explained/

An alternate definition seems to refer to a "document style" or "global style", as in [the CSS1 Spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS1/), although this is not as common:

> CSS1 is a simple style sheet mechanism that allows authors and readers to attach style (e.g. fonts, colors and spacing) to HTML documents.

Comment: A single declaration can contain multiple styles. (i.e. `border: 1px solid black;` is one declaration but contains 3 styles.)

Comment: So it can happend for example that just one of the three styles gets overwritten. (i.e. `border-width: 2px;`)

Comment: @FabianBarney That's a good point, can you post that as an answer?